# Change and Input events on Programmatic injection

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm reformulating my question since it wasn't clear the first time and I've already edited my other question too many times.  I think it's sufficiently different that it shouldn't be considered a repeat question due to the browser extension clarification.

This event listener is for a browser extension interacting with a personal webpage that has the element updated via the server after the page was loaded (I'm just using a prompt to simulate the delayed update of an element here).  This is a debugging script to add an input event listener for an element so as to call another function once the element was given its input programmatically, right now, the event listener only runs when it get's its input manually.  If everything was being called within one script, I could have skipped the extra event listener and simply call the function after updating the element, but the extension execution flow is separate so the event listener needs to be separate.

HTML Webpage

```
<textarea id="fI"></textarea>
<button type="button" id='pressMe'>Press Me</button>
<textarea id="example2"></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("pressMe").addEventListener("click",doSomething);
function doSomething () {
  var something = prompt("Please enter something", "something");
  if (something !== null) {
    document.getElementById("fI").innerHTML = something;
  }
}
```

Browser Extension Content Script

```
document.getElementById("fI").addEventListener("input", blabla);
function blabla() {
  var something = document.getElementById("fI").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML = something+" continue the rest of the script here";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I'm not exactly sure whether you're controlling the change of the value and not getting the event, or whether another script is controlling the change of value and you're not getting the event.

If you're doing assignment, and want an event to propagate, then you can do the following:

```
element.value = "a change that I want to fire an event.";
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

If you're wanting to get the event when something else programmatically changes the value, then you might be out of luck for catching an event. In that case you could poll on the value using a setInterval, though this is pretty blech.

```
function callOnValueChange(element, callback, once) {
     var initialValue = element.value,
         check;
     check = setInterval(function() {
         if (element.value !== initialValue) {
             callback.call(element);
             initialValue = element.value;
             if (once) clearInterval(check);     
         }
     }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Could use Mutation Observers to achieve the second part in an event-based fashion.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't ever used a mutation observer. But after playing around a bit it seems that this would only work if you were assigning the value of the text area using text nodes, rather than the value property.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lpfpqfh/1/

Comment: Above fiddle had a spelling error to the MutationObserverInit object where I used 'attribute' rather than 'attributes'. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Lpfpqfh/2/ shows the same behaviour with correct spelling. My bad.

Comment: I really thought that dispatchEvent was going to work but it didn't...  Yes, I'm controlling all scripts in this scenario, it's just I have to have the Extension script respond to an HTML element being updated via a server script that's also mine...  This is basically how my code is set up http://jsfiddle.net/z474no4n/1/, except the event listener isn't in the same file...  Perhaps there's another step involved for extensions to recognize the custom event?

Comment: It may be related to when the extension's script is injected. Though the Chrome default seems to be after document ready and before/slightly after window load: [docs for chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). The [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) keyword may help you track/understand what is going on after you've dispatched the event. When all else fails chucking console logs everywhere to see what is/isn't being fired can help.